# Pick month from a list in UITableViewCell?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uipickerview

What's the best way for me to allow the user to pick a month from a UITableViewCell? UIPickerView requires the height to be very large which makes it look ugly..What are some other options? I don't want to put a text field there and manually make the user enter a month..
Thanks.

Comment: The UIPickerView takes up just 35% of the screen... the same size as the keyboard. It is the best view for picking dates and gives an awesome experience to the user.

Comment: How can I show UIPickerView instead of UIKeyboard then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
datePicker.tag = indexPath.row;
textField.delegate= self;

textField.inputView = datePicker; // Now the Keyboard will not appear //

[datePicker release];
```